# Get User ID from Devise, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use Devise and Basic HTTP Authentication to access user areas from a mobile app. When the user enters its details in the app and it tries to "login" (you don't actually login with basic auth as you send the credentials with each request) I want to get a response back with the user info, like user ID and email.

When I try to get a resource I get a response like this:

```
[
 -
 {
    email: "em...@example.com"
    username: "Example"
 }
 -
  [
  -
  {
     created_at: "2011-07-26T11:30:55Z"
     id: 1
     title: "Test"
     updated_at: "2011-07-26T11:30:55Z"
     user_id: 1
  }
  -
  {
     created_at: "2011-07-26T16:53:26Z"
     id: 2
     title: "Test2"
     updated_at: "2011-07-26T16:53:26Z"
     user_id: 1
  }
 ]
]
```

So I get the user object at the beginning. However, I need to add the user ID as well. I can't use the user_id in the items because that won't be rendered if the user has no items.

Any tips?

Comment: Ok. Adding attr_accessible :id to my model works. But is it safe to do it like this?

Comment: @Dex Isn't it possible to make the attribute accessible but read only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to extend `Devise::SessionsConroller`. In your controllers folder, add a users folder and then add a file called `sessions_controller.rb`that contains this:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    super
    render :json => {:id => current_user.id}.to_json
  end
end
```

In `your routes.rb`:

```
  devise_for  :users, 
              :controllers => {:sessions => 'users/sessions'}
```

EDIT

Try this. Take that line out of your `routes.rb`. In `application_controller.rb` add this:

```
  # Devise override
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
    render :json => {:id => resource.id}.to_json
  end
```

Comment: this doesn't work `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id` When I try to sign in through the web.

Comment: current_user must not be getting set yet for your initial error. Put in a debugger statement after `super` and see which variables and methods are available.

Answer (score 0):

after an aftternoon to try to find a good answer, i've found this:

> Resource: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models

Hope it Helps!